# Is there a shorter way to prove that $\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}x^{2j}\over (1+x^{2n})(-\ln{x})^{1\over s}}dx...?$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Is there a shorter way to show that

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}x^{2j}\over (1+x^{2n})(-\ln{x})^{1\over s}}dx=\Gamma\left(s-1\over s\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sqrt[s]{2i-1}\over 2i-1}\tag1$$

Take a simple case, $ n=1$ and $s=2$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{1\over (-\ln{x})^{1\over 2}}dx=\Gamma(1/2)\tag2$$

$(2)$ is a well known integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}(-\ln{x})^ndx=n!$$

Take  another case, $n=2$ and $s=2$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{1+x^2+x^4+x^6\over (1+x^4)(-\ln{x})^{1\over 2}}dx=\Gamma(1/2)\left(1+{\sqrt3\over 3}\right)\tag3$$

Simplify $(3)$ then we have

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x^2\over (-\ln{x})^{1\over 2}}dx={\sqrt{3\pi}\over 3}\tag4$$

substitution $t=-\ln{x}$

Hence

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-3t}t^{-1/2}dt={\sqrt{3\pi}\over 3}\tag5$$

Then use standard integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-at}t^ndt={\Gamma(1+n)\over a^{n+1}}$$

---

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}x^{2j}=\frac{x^{4n}-1}{x^2-1}=\frac{(x^{2n}-1)(x^{2n}+1)}{x^2-1}$$

Comment: A shorter way than which way?

Comment: another hint: telescoping will be very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is sufficient “short”, however is a way. We have $$\begin{align}
I= & \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}x^{2j}}{\left(1+x^{2n}\right)\left(-\log\left(x\right)\right)^{1/s}}dx \\ = & \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{4n}-1}{\left(1+x^{2n}\right)\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(-\log\left(x\right)\right)^{1/s}}dx \\ = & \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2n}-1}{\left(x^{2}-1\right)\left(-\log\left(x\right)\right)^{1/s}}dx
\end{align}
 $$ now take $-\log\left(x\right)=t$. We get $$\begin{align}
I= & \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2nt}-1}{e^{-2t}-1}t^{-1/s}e^{-t}dt \\ = & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2t\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}t^{-1/s}dt \\
 \overset{2t\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=u}{=} & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}\left(\frac{u}{2k+1}\right)^{-1/s}\frac{du}{2k+1} \\ = & \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(2k+1\right)^{1/s-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-1/s}du
\end{align}
 $$ and so

> $$I=\color{red}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{1}{s}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(2k+1\right)^{1/s}}{2k+1}.}$$

Comment: to be honest, i don't think it will get any shorter +1